# Group Up specific prices

Tags: mysql

Table:Transaction Header  / Column :Payments

I wish to make a query to see the payments line with this form :

Column A : 0-5 - Column B : Count the Payments - Column C :Sum the Payments

Column A : 6-10 - Column B : Count the Payments - Column C :Sum the Payments

Column A : 10+ - Column B : Count the Payments  - Column C :Sum the Payments

i see the CASE is what i need but i can not find a way to use it. Can you please help ? Please use also the table and column name in the solution

Thank you in Advance,
Kostas

Comment: Do I understand you well, that you want to group by price range? 0-5, 6-10 and 10+ are these ranges?

Comment: some example/exact data from your table(s) will be more than helpful

Comment: Exacty... 
Row 1: 0-5 | 2 (receipts) | 45 (sum of the payment of the 1st column of those 2 receipts)
Row 2: 5-10 | 3 | 50 and so on...